# ext gwt remove(Widget) issue

Tags: gwt, extjs

i have an vertical panel (boxContent) with three horizontal panels (row1, row2 and row3). I want to remove the second row, so I'm using following:

```
boxContent.remove(row2)
```

The content of the row is removed, but the row still exist with following content

```
<tr>
<td class="x-table-layout-cell" align="left" valign="top"/>
</tr>
```

How can i remove the row completly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was, that i'm putting the third row in new panel and not in the same, which contains first and second row....now is `remove(row2)` working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try **FlexTable** instead of vertical and horizontal panel.

Have not try it, but it might be the solution to your problem.